# Integrating JSPM + BABEL + BOWER + GULP + REACTJS + ASP.NET 5 in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, gulp, bower, jspm

I'm using *Visual Studio 2015* and created a *ASP.NET 5* web application. I have a simple **ReactJS** component which fails at the line

```
var _react = require('react');
```

Instead of using *webpack/browserify*, I tried to install **JSPM** which can do (1) JSX compilation to JS through *Babel* and (2) module management to support **require**.

Scott Allen on this [page](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/02/18/using-jspm-with-visual-studio-2015-and-asp-net-5.aspx) talks about integrating JPSM to a ASP.NET 5 project. I can make this work temporarily, but I want to have a task in **gulp** to copy the system.js to the wwwroot as part of a build process. I have already a **package.json** which I don't want to be over written when I run the JPSM init commandline.

I installed JSPM through **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ASP.NET",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "3.8.11",
    "gulp-concat": "2.5.2",
    "gulp-cssmin": "0.1.7",
    "gulp-uglify": "1.2.0",
    "rimraf": "2.2.8",
    "jspm": "0.15.7"
  }
}
```

How to integrate all these pieces together to have a good build setup?

1. How to create a JSPM system.js file using Gulp?
2. How the task will look like creating JS files from JSX using JSPM and Babel?
3. Should I install requires or similar packages to get the module loading functionality with **require** keyword?